# GetFallbackPolicyAsync error when upgrading to .NetCore3.1

Tags: .net-core-3.1, .net-core-2.2

I have an API originally having .net core V2.2 and referencing a .net Standard Dll where I'm having a specific implementation of **IAuthorizationPolicyProvider** interface.
However, when upgrading the API to .net core V3.1, I had the following error :

```
'Method 'GetFallbackPolicyAsync' in type 'xxx' from assembly 'xxx' does not have an implementation.'
```

Based on the following link (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/2.2-3.0), I've added the **GetFallbackPolicyAsync** like the below :

```
public Task<AuthorizationPolicy> GetFallbackPolicyAsync() => Task.FromResult<AuthorizationPolicy>(null);
```

But the same error occurs.
Any idea what could be the cause?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the problem.
I have a DLL referenced in the project containing an older version of **Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization**. I had to install latest version Authorization dll from nugget containing an implementation of the **GetFallbackPolicyAsync** method.